# vue-router beforeRouteUpdate hook can't access `this`

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a Vue.js application using vue-router.

From the [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) I can read that inside the hook `beforeRouteUpdate` I have full access to the component through the keyword `this`:

> Note that beforeRouteEnter is the only guard that supports passing a
>   callback to next. For beforeRouteUpdate and beforeRouteLeave, this is
>   already available, so passing a callback is unnecessary and therefore
>   not supported:

So I wrote the following code:

```
    ...
    methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        setFileDetails: 'setFileDetails',
        setActionParams: 'setActionParams',
        setSelectedFileId: 'setSelectedFileId',
      }),
      goToImportSource() {
        this.$router.push('/import');
      },
      openAnnotationsView(item) {
        this.$router.push(`/ingestion/queue/${item.id}`);
      },
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate: (
      to,
      from,
      next,
    ) => {
      this.setSelectedFileId(to.params.id);
      next();
    },
  };
</script>
```

But I get this error:

```
vue-router.esm.js?fe87:16 [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:

TypeError: _this.setSelectedFileId is not a function
    at VueComponent.beforeRouteUpdate (PageIngestionQueue.vue?3869:67)
    at boundRouteGuard (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2080)
    at iterator (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1943)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1717)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1721)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1721)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1721)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1718)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1964)
    at eval (routeRules.js?b464:9)
```

If I call `this.setSelectedFileId` anywhere else in the component it works...what am I missing?

Comment: Use function instead of arrow syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `function() {}` instead of `() => {}` syntax (the latter will bind `this` which you don't want here):

```es6
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  this.setSelectedFileId(to.params.id);
  next();
}
```

or

```es6
beforeRouteUpdate: function(to, from, next) {
  this.setSelectedFileId(to.params.id);
  next();
}
```